# Hardware defect detection: Computer crashes after 1 hour

Tags: windows, ssd, crash

My config:
i5 2500
Asus P8P67 Deluxe
Asus HD6900
16 GB CORSAIR Vengeance
Crucial SSD 60GB
and 2 x 1TB HDD in Raid 0

Everything has been working fine for a year or so on Windows 7. Since Wednesday the computer crashes every hour or so, with a blue screen. It reboots and doesn't see the SSD at startup (so doesn't boot). If I shut down properly and wait 10 secs I see it again, then it crashes again after one hour. CPU and MB temperature are normal.

I had installed Dragon Naturally Speaking and some Windows update earlier so I tried uninstalling. After having uninstalled nearly everything from my machine, I reinstalled the OS, this time Windows 8, on the same SSD after formatting it. After one hour or so, the opened softwares start to be in a Non Responding state one by one, and task manager stops responding too - without having shown anything abnormal. Then I need to manually force shut down as everything is frozen.

I'm about to go buy a new SSD, but I was wondering if anyone had a better idea...

Comment: Do you have a second computer or a laptop? Then you can test the possibly broken SSD in that computer. If it also starts crashing after one hour you confirmed your problem.

Comment: You mean to reinstall an OS on another machine with this same drive? Or can I try using the OS already installed without messing it up? But yeah I should certainly do that, good point

Comment: Correct. E.g. remove the existing drive from a laptop (which will not be changed in any way). Replace it with the SSD, do a clean install and see if the laptop is stable. If not, write broken on the SSD and replace the original laptop drive.  And where I write laptop you can ofcourse also use any other computer.

Comment: I gonna try it now

Comment: Could be bad RAM. Give memtest a go.

Comment: Aye. could be a whole lot of problems. But programs hanging one by one *sound* (ok, that is a fuzzy description but I do not have abetter one) as if something hangs on IO. Which can be the drive, the chipset, or even a bad cable.

Comment: That was the SSD! I've put it on my other pc on and it crashed after 50mn. Really weird that delay... Anyway, I've changed the SSD and now the machine is on for 2 hours and it's fine! @Hennes: thanks, that was pretty basic troubleshouting but I hadn't thought about it!

Comment: It is always easier from the outside when there is no pressure or no frustration. :)

Comment: Also, it the SSD still under warranty ?

Comment: Yes, it's my second Crucial SSD failing in 18 month. I just bought an Intel , and will definitely send this one back.

Answer (score 3):

In case you still have this problem, try updating the firmware of your SSD. I had the exact same problems over the last few days (shutdown after 1 hour, unable to boot etc.) and the firmware-update solved everything. This is a known issue with Cruical SSDs.

Answer (score 1):

Download CrystalDiskInfo (http://bit.ly/8Z4RJS) it will tell you by using SMART attributes if anything is wrong with your SSD. If so replace it.

Otherwise get Memtest86 (http://www.memtest.org/#downiso) auto-installer for USB key preferably and boot from it. Let it run one complete pass. If errors occur replace defective RAM modules.

Comment: I'll sure do that next time